# how can i filter duplicate keys?

Tags: javascript, object

```
const bible = [
   {
      "id":1001001,
      "Book":"Genesis",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":1,
      "Text":"In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth."
   },
   {
      "id":1001002,
      "Book":"Genesis",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":2,
      "Text":"And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters."
   },
   {
      "id":1001003,
      "Book":"Genesis",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":3,
      "Text":"And God said, Let there be light: and there was light."
   },
   {
      "id":1001004,
      "Book":"Exodus",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":4,
      "Text":"And God saw the light, that it was good: and God divided the light from the darkness."
   },
   {
      "id":1001005,
      "Book":"Exodus",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":5,
      "Text":"And God called the light Day, and the darkness he called Night. And the evening and the morning were the first day."
   },
   {
      "id":1001006,
      "Book":"Genesis",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":6,
      "Text":"And God said, Let there be a firmament in the midst of the waters, and let it divide the waters from the waters."
   },
   {
      "id":1001007,
      "Book":"Revelation",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":7,
      "Text":"And God made the firmament, and divided the waters which were under the firmament from the waters which were above the firmament: and it was so."
   },
   {
      "id":1001008,
      "Book":"Revelation",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":8,
      "Text":"And God called the firmament Heaven. And the evening and the morning were the second day."
   },
   {
      "id":1001009,
      "Book":"Genesis",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":9,
      "Text":"And God said, Let the waters under the heaven be gathered together unto one place, and let the dry land appear: and it was so."
   },
   {
      "id":1001010,
      "Book":"Genesis",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":10,
      "Text":"And God called the dry land Earth; and the gathering together of the waters called he Seas: and God saw that it was good."
   }
]
```

How can i return an array with no duplicate bible.Book ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) along with [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

```
const res = bible.filter((x,idx)=>bible.findIndex(y=>y.Book===x.Book)===idx);
```

```js
const bible = [
   {
      "id":1001001,
      "Book":"Genesis",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":1,
      "Text":"In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth."
   },
   {
      "id":1001002,
      "Book":"Genesis",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":2,
      "Text":"And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters."
   },
   {
      "id":1001003,
      "Book":"Genesis",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":3,
      "Text":"And God said, Let there be light: and there was light."
   },
   {
      "id":1001004,
      "Book":"Exodus",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":4,
      "Text":"And God saw the light, that it was good: and God divided the light from the darkness."
   },
   {
      "id":1001005,
      "Book":"Exodus",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":5,
      "Text":"And God called the light Day, and the darkness he called Night. And the evening and the morning were the first day."
   },
   {
      "id":1001006,
      "Book":"Genesis",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":6,
      "Text":"And God said, Let there be a firmament in the midst of the waters, and let it divide the waters from the waters."
   },
   {
      "id":1001007,
      "Book":"Revelation",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":7,
      "Text":"And God made the firmament, and divided the waters which were under the firmament from the waters which were above the firmament: and it was so."
   },
   {
      "id":1001008,
      "Book":"Revelation",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":8,
      "Text":"And God called the firmament Heaven. And the evening and the morning were the second day."
   },
   {
      "id":1001009,
      "Book":"Genesis",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":9,
      "Text":"And God said, Let the waters under the heaven be gathered together unto one place, and let the dry land appear: and it was so."
   },
   {
      "id":1001010,
      "Book":"Genesis",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":10,
      "Text":"And God called the dry land Earth; and the gathering together of the waters called he Seas: and God saw that it was good."
   }
];
const res = bible.filter((x,idx)=>bible.findIndex(y=>y.Book===x.Book)===idx);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: this only returns one time genesis. i want it to return all the objects. but not 2 times the same bible.Book

Comment: @IlseVanDommelen What do you mean? My answer filters out all other objects with the same `Book` property. What is the expected output?

Comment: const filter = [
   {
      "id":1001001,
      "Book":"Genesis",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":1,
      "Text":"In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth."
   },
   {
      "id":1001004,
      "Book":"Exodus",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":4,
      "Text":"And God saw the light, that it was good: and God divided the light from the darkness."
   }
]

Comment: one time genesis, one time exodus etc etc

Comment: @IlseVanDommelen What is wrong with the output of my answer?

Comment: your output gives me only one object.

Comment: @IlseVanDommelen It outputs an array with 3 objects. Have you run the snippet?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const bible = [
   {
      "id":1001001,
      Book:"Genesis",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":1,
      "Text":"In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth."
   },
   {
      "id":1001002,
      Book:"Genesis",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":2,
      "Text":"And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters."
   },
   {
      "id":1001003,
      Book:"Genesis",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":3,
      "Text":"And God said, Let there be light: and there was light."
   },
   {
      "id":1001004,
      Book:"Exodus",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":4,
      "Text":"And God saw the light, that it was good: and God divided the light from the darkness."
   },
   {
      "id":1001005,
      Book:"Exodus",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":5,
      "Text":"And God called the light Day, and the darkness he called Night. And the evening and the morning were the first day."
   },
   {
      "id":1001006,
      Book:"Genesis",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":6,
      "Text":"And God said, Let there be a firmament in the midst of the waters, and let it divide the waters from the waters."
   },
   {
      "id":1001007,
      Book:"Revelation",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":7,
      "Text":"And God made the firmament, and divided the waters which were under the firmament from the waters which were above the firmament: and it was so."
   },
   {
      "id":1001008,
      Book:"Revelation",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":8,
      "Text":"And God called the firmament Heaven. And the evening and the morning were the second day."
   },
   {
      "id":1001009,
      Book:"Genesis",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":9,
      "Text":"And God said, Let the waters under the heaven be gathered together unto one place, and let the dry land appear: and it was so."
   },
   {
      "id":1001010,
      Book:"Genesis",
      "Chapter":1,
      "Verse":10,
      "Text":"And God called the dry land Earth; and the gathering together of the waters called he Seas: and God saw that it was good."
   }
];

const filtered = bible.filter((book, index, bible) => !bible.some((book2, index2) => (book.Book === book2.Book) && (index > index2)));

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: when i console.log(filtered) it gives me back an empty array.

Comment: I fixed it and made a snippet

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what i ment.

Answer (score 1):

Using `map` to get the list of books and using `Set` which will remove the duplicates for you

```js
var bible = [
  { Book: 'Genesis'},
  { Book: 'Exodus'},
  { Book: 'Revelation'},
  { Book: 'Genesis'},
  { Book: 'Exodus'},
  { Book: 'Revelation'},
  { Book: 'Genesis'},
  { Book: 'Exodus'},
  { Book: 'Revelation'},
]

const books = [...new Set(bible.map(b => b.Book))];
console.log(books);
```

Or you can use using `reduce` with `Object.keys`

```js
var bible = [
  { Book: 'Genesis'},
  { Book: 'Exodus'},
  { Book: 'Revelation'},
  { Book: 'Genesis'},
  { Book: 'Exodus'},
  { Book: 'Revelation'},
  { Book: 'Genesis'},
  { Book: 'Exodus'},
  { Book: 'Revelation'},
]

const books = Object.keys(bible.reduce((o, item) => (o[item.Book] = 1, o), {}));
console.log(books);
```

Comment: this gives only back the book genesis. i need it to give back genesis,exodus and revelation

Comment: Um, not sure where you are only getting back one book.

Comment: sorry. you are right. thank you very much for you help.